# Compare multiple field to single IN query

Tags: postgresql-9.3, subquery

I have a situation where I need to compare 3 different fields of a same table to a single IN query, eg:

```
SELECT unit
FROM trips
WHERE owner1,owner2,owner3 in (select id from login)
```

Can this be done in PostgreSQL?

Using version 9.3.4

Comment: I agree with Craig below, *You haven't supplied a clear definition of the problem, so I have to guess you probably mean "if any of these field values are in this list" or "if all of these field values are in this list".*

Answer (score 4):

You haven't supplied a clear definition of the problem, so I have to guess you probably mean "if any of these field values are in this list" or "if all of these field values are in this list".

Either way, you'll want to use logical array operators. The "any" case is array-overlaps, `&&`:

```
ARRAY[owner1,owner2,owner3] && (select array_agg(id) from login)
```

and the "all" case is array-contains, `<@`:

```
ARRAY[owner1,owner2,owner3] <@ (select array_agg(id) from login)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must construct that SELECT query separately (e.g. because the actual query you are comparing against is significantly more complicated than just `SELECT id FROM login`), I would put your query against `login` in a CTE, so that it only needs to be evaluated once, something like this:

```
WITH my_ids AS (
  SELECT id FROM login
)
   SELECT trips.unit
     FROM trips
LEFT JOIN my_ids AS my_ids1
       ON my_ids1.id = test_unit.owner1
LEFT JOIN my_ids AS my_ids2
       ON my_ids2.id = test_unit.owner2
LEFT JOIN my_ids AS my_ids3 ON my_ids3.id = test_unit.owner3
    WHERE (my_ids1.id IS NOT NULL OR my_ids2.id IS NOT NULL OR my_ids3.id IS NOT NULL);
```

And if you don't have to write that `(SELECT id FROM login)` as a separate CTE, you could of course just LEFT JOIN directly against `login` instead of `my_ids`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same case recently and it appeared to be not that trivial! There is a variety of ways to achieve the goal, providing different performance, so after some investigation I ended up with a little benchmark. Assuming that we need to know if **any** of the columns is contained by the second relation:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a, a + 1 as b
FROM generate_series( 1, 100000 ) _( a );

ANALYZE t1;

CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS
SELECT c * 100 as c
FROM generate_series( 1, 100 ) _( c );

ANALYZE t2;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE WITH t1_count as (
    SELECT count(*) FROM t1
), t2_count as (
    SELECT count(*) FROM t2
    -- the two above are to eliminate the possible
    -- first-time-access penalty between the compared CTE's
), t_or_in as (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM t1
    WHERE a IN( SELECT c FROM t2 )
        OR b IN( SELECT c FROM t2 )
), t_array as (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM t1
    WHERE ARRAY[a,b] && ( SELECT array_agg( c ) FROM t2 )
), t_exists as (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM t1
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM t2
        WHERE c IN( a, b )
    )
), t_join_1 as (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 t2a ON a = t2a.c
    LEFT JOIN t2 t2b ON b = t2b.c
    WHERE t2a IS NOT NULL
        OR t2b IS NOT NULL
), t_join_2 as (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON c IN( a, b )
)
SELECT *
FROM t1_count, t2_count, t_or_in,
    t_array, t_exists, t_join_1, t_join_2
```

You can take the ready results [from here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/rN23), got them on my local environment with Postgres 9.6. Short summary:

```
t_or_in      51 ms
t_join_1     61 ms
t_array     262 ms
t_join_2   3140 ms
t_exists   5184 ms
```

Surprisingly, the most graceful (IMO) form of inner-joining the target relations (`t_join_2`) showed indecently slow performance! Something must be wrong with the planner. Various simple tricks did not help, it tends to make the nested loop scan on one or another table. Not sure, maybe this was not that bad in case we had a good index on one of them but still the other 3 forms are producing much better plans without any hacks.

Otherwise the stats are more or less predictable - the forms with array and subquery are notably slower than the `LEFT JOIN` and the simple `IN` condition.

**Note 1**: As you could notice, the compared queries are not strictly equal. Keep that in mind: you may need to enforce uniqueness of the rows from `t1` as they may get multiplied by the `JOIN` statements.

**Note 2**: I can't tell for sure that CTEs are to provide reliable timing under all conditions so it is worth double checking the results by running the queries independently, in case if you want to reproduce this test or if you're going to write your own in the same manner.

**Note 3**: The provided stats are purely synthetic and are only applicable to this particular setting. If you

- change the number of rows in either relation
- change the condition itself
- try this on another version of Postgres
- involve the real, indexed tables with heavy data

that may affect the results in either way... However, I hope this is still useful for someone around.

Comment: You should run each query individually, not as one giant query (even though each CTE is planned independently I am not sure this is a valid way of timing multiple queries)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, independent runs of those queries give me `48 / 62 / 262 / 3160 / 5190 ms`, respectively to the stats mentioned above. Pretty much the same... I don't know if this is a valid way of benchmarking in general but I don't see anything wrong with this particular case so far. Unified them into one mainly for convenience.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But you're right, we can't say for sure that the timing for CTEs is always that strict under all versions of postgres and other conditions. I'll add this to the answer.